# Why does this sentence use 'where' instead of 'when'?

Tags: word-choice

I am playing a game and it says

> *The day finally came where you take over the throne*

Why is it using "where" rather than "when"? Is it correct?

Comment: This example has an unrelated grammar problem.  "Came" is past tense, but "take over" is present tense.  Either of these options would be more consistent:  "The day finally came where you took over the throne", or "The day finally comes where you take over the throne".  In both of these revised examples, "when" could be substituted for "where".

Comment: @Jasper thanks very much for the reminder. I guess it's me remembering a wrong word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The adverb "when" is used not only to refer to time (at what/which time, at the time that, etc.) but also an occasion or a situation (on which occasion or in which situation).

The same is with the adverb "where" that is used not only to refer to a place but also an occasion or a situation.

So it's in the sense of "occasion or situation", both adverbs are interchangeable. Look up the meaning of situation in Oxford Dictionary for more understanding).

Answer (score 3):

*When* is far more common as a relative with expressions of time - there are 3,931 COCA citations for 'day when' and only 241 for 'day where'. However,  *where* is possible. Presumably those who use *where* take the idea of '**location** in time'  more literally than those who use  *when.*