# The "day where" vs "day when"?

Tags: grammar

> I long for the day where I will be able to see my kids.
>
> I long for the day when I will be able to see my kids.

I heard they are interchangeable, but I am wondering if in this situation this can be considered to be correct.

Comment: It should be "I long for the day **when...**" They're not interchangeable. "I long for a place *where...*" OR "I long for a/the time *when*".

Comment: There are books that use "the day where i will"

Comment: "Longing for the day where there might be a chance to escape, ending the tortuous nightmare."

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38434/why-does-this-sentence-use-where-instead-of-when

Comment: Please look at [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+day+when%2Cthe+day+where&year_start=1800&year_end=20)! Did you read the *second* answer at ...38434?  You asked if *where* and *when* were interchangeable. If you had asked whether, in certain circumstances, you could use one rather than the other, you might have got a different answer. There are lots of mistakes in books. Google doesn't find the line you quoted. What is the book?